# Need help to visualise Topological Puzzle

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics, education

I am curious about this puzzle on unlinking the fingers of a rubber man. 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=olHV4qvSDg8)

However, despite the illustrations in the above video, I can't visualize the step (C) to (D). I am ok with (D) to (E).

[image]

Can anyone describe what is going on from (C) to (D)? Or even better, any links to a clearer animation?

Comment: Try this video instead, for a Russian (and slightly creepy!) take on the same subject: https://vk.com/video-9666747_142799479

Comment: The video is amazing!

Comment: For a reference, it's video #10 from http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/polthier/video/VideoMath98/index.html

Comment: Is there a name for this topological phenomenon?